# Failed to parse command output (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, github, autoload, dump, command-line-tool

So this is what I got when I try to add the Symfony tool (Symfony version : 3..)

The project was created from another machine and cloned into mine (Git)

I could make the necessary changes for composer.phar and php.exe when adding the Composer tool and I had no problem concerning that but when it comes to add the Symfony tool I got a " Failed to parse command output " error message and there are the details of the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik0Ph.png)

What should I do?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, yours paths contain both "/" and "\". I think this happened because you create the project in a linux/unix machine and now you are working on Windows.

Path problem is in composer files. Is vendor folder committed in the repository? If yes, remove it and re run `composer install`.